# Probability of getting loops

Tags: probability

**You are given $3$ bits of lace, if ends are tied together at random, what is the probability that you end up with $2$ loops?**

**Generalise this for $n$ bits of lace.**

Ok so clearly I have 6 ends to play with, the first end I take can be tied to a possible 5 other ends, then the next one has 3 ends it could be tied to, and the next has only 1 end
So there are $5*3*1=15$ possible outcome
Then to see the chances of getting two loops, I labelled each end with a letter and wrote out all possible combinations that result in 2 loops. There turn out to be 6 different ways, so the probability is $6/15$

My method clearly isn't ideal for finding out a general solution

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can derive a recurrence as follows: Take one end of one bit of lace and tie it to a random end. With probability $1/(2n-1)$ you form a loop and have $n-1$ bits of lace left to tie; with probability $(2n-2)/(2n-1)$ you don't form a loop and also have $n-1$ bits of lace left to tie. Thus if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are the probability that $n$ bits of lace are tied into $1$ and $2$ loops, respectively, we have

$$
b_n=\frac1{2n-1}\left(a_{n-1}+(2n-2)b_{n-1}\right)\;.
$$

Similar reasoning also yields

$$
a_n=\frac{2n-2}{2n-1}a_{n-1}\;.
$$

The initial values are $a_1=1$ and $b_1=0$. The solution, which can be guessed from some initial terms and then proved by induction, is

$$
a_n=\frac{4^{n-1}(n-1)!^2}{(2n-1)!}
$$

and

$$
b_n=\frac12a_nH_{n-1}\;,
$$

where

$$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$

is the $n$-th harmonic number.

For $n=3$, we have

$$
a_3=\frac{4^22!^2}{5!}=\frac8{15}
$$

and

$$
b_3=\frac12\cdot\frac8{15}\cdot\frac32=\frac25\;,
$$

in agreement with your result.

Comment: I've been staring at this for ages... I feel it's too complicated for what it is, is there no simpler way?

Comment: Thank you for your answer by the way